# Which IC Component is this?

Tags: components, microchip

I seem to have burned out this chip on my Hobby King ESC (See picture). I am not able to read the component Part number. The ESC is no longer available to buy. Could someone please name the part number so that I may fix it?  Thanks in advance.

[HobbyKing 40A (2~6S) ESC w/UBEC 4A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4GwE.jpg)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CherryDT Sounds fair. Should I delete the question?